# Does OpenSSL has any event callback function for 'Read' data?

Tags: c++, winapi, client, openssl, visual-c++

I was looking for event callback function when OpenSSL has incoming 'Read' data. Does OpenSSL has this kind of function? If yes, could you please show me some example code please?

I'm thinking to write a simple wrapper for my application. This wrapper will make a callback when data arrive. My initial thought would be create a thread looping in non-blocking mode to scan for any incoming data. And when data arrived, I'll just make the callback. Am I doing the right thing here?

Thanks a lot for answering! And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html) has support for asynchronous SSL read operations.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but is there anything more specific to OpenSSL?

Comment: I'm not aware of callbacks specific to OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

The [CyaSSL SSL library](http://www.yassl.com) (similar to OpenSSL, but with a much smaller footprint and other cool features) has I/O callbacks similar to what you are looking for I believe.

In CyaSSL, the input/output callbacks are prototyped by **CallbackIOSend** and **CallbackIORecv** in ssl.h.  These functions need to be registered per SSL_CTX with **CyaSSL_SetIOSend()** and **CyaSSL_SetIORecv()**.  The default case (CBIOSend() and CBIORecv() are registered at the bottom of cyassl_io.c.

The CBIOSend and CBIORecv function pointers can be pointed to your custom I/O functions. You can use the default Send() and Receive() functions (EmbedSend() and EmbedReceive(), located in cyassl_io.c) as examples.

Regards,
Chris